# How to create a created_by field in django rest framework model?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to create a created_by field in django rest framework model.

It should contain, user_id of currently logged in user and it should be such that I need not send it during POST request in JSON format, it should be taken from request itself, how can I implement it using django rest framework serializer.

models.py file:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    """Company model for information about company."""

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null= True, blank= True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

serializers.py file:

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""Serializer for companies."""

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('id', 'created_by', 'company_name')
```

v1.py file:

```
class CompanyList(APIView):
"""Get and post companies data."""

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        """Get companies data.."""
        companies = Company.objects.all()
        serialized_companies = CompanySerializer(companies, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_companies.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        """Post companies data."""
        serializer = CompanySerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Method-1: Using [`CurrentUserDefault()`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault) option**

You can pass `default` parameter in `created_by` field as `serializers.CurrentUserDefault()` which will set its value as the current user.

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""Serializer for companies."""

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('id', 'created_by', 'company_name')
        extra_kwargs = {'created_by': {'default': serializers.CurrentUserDefault()}}
```

**Method-2: Passing `user` in `serializer.save()`**

You can set the field `created_by` as `read_only` and then pass `request.user` to `serializer.save()`.

**serializers.py**

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""Serializer for companies."""

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('id', 'created_by', 'company_name')
        extra_kwargs = {'created_by': {'read_only':True}}
```

**v1.py**

```
class CompanyList(APIView):
"""Get and post companies data."""

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        """Post companies data."""
        serializer = CompanySerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(created_by=request.user) # pass current user
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `serializers.CurrentUserDefault()` as default for the `created_by` field in the `CompanySerializer` and make that field `read_only=True`.

See the docs [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields).

Comment: Somehow it is not working.  It gives IntegrityError: Column 'created_by_id' cannot be null. If I leave the read_only=True, it works. But then I can also set it to something else, like another user...

Comment: @gabn88 agreed, I see this as well. Both Rahul Gupta's methods worked for me. This one does not.

Comment: Its really elegant but does not work for me as well, I get same error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "created_by_id" violates not-null constraint`

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

models.py file

```
class Student(models.Model):
    middel_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

here it's my serializer file

```
class GetStudentUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

class GetStudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = GetStudentUserSerializer('user.username')
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('id','middel_name','user')
        depth = 1

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print "hello"
        student_data = validated_data.pop('student', None)
        user = super(GetStudentSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        self.create_or_update_student(user, student_data)
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        student_data = validated_data.pop('student', None)
        self.create_or_update_student(instance, student_data)
        return super(GetStudentSerializer, self).update(instance, student_data)

    def create_or_update_student(self, user, student_data):
        student, created = Student.objects.get_or_create(user=user, defaults=student_data)
        if not created and student_data is not None:
        super(GetStudentSerializer, self).update(instance, student_data)
```